# Clarification on MongoDB bind_ip Flag

Tags: mongodb

I was reading around the MongoDb documentation and I noticed a [bind_ip](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#bind_ip) flag you can set for your `mongod` instance.

From what I gathered after reading, it appears as though you can use this in your configuration file to make MongoDB only respond from connections from the specific IP address(es).

Digging around on the internet to get more information it would appear as though it [doesn't do what I expect it to](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/t5VZd8Ir4Vc) (check last comment).  It may be old/ inaccurate though, it is a few years old.

So am I right?  Does the bind_ip limit what external IP's can connect to the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bind_ip does not put a limit on external IP addresses. It will bind your mongod instance to a specific network interface on the machine it is running on.

So for example if you had a server in which there were 2 network cards, one which interfaced with a private internal network and a second which interfaced with a public, less secure network. You could bind mongod to the private card/interface so that it would only accept connections across your private network.

Comment: Any suggestions on how you might actually force a MongoDB instance to only talk to localhost and not external ip addresses? I'm guessing this is what the OP was hoping `--bind_ip` would achieve.

Comment: @shennan I did want something like that, but I found an [easier and probably more secure solution](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#auth) (iptables always seems to reset at odd times).